# Wrapping the_content() in Schema articleBody tag?

Tags: php, seo

I am trying to put `the_content()` inside `<meta itemprop="articleBody" content="`(content here)`">`.

But if I just put `<?php the_content() ?>` in there, it doesn't work, image goes, structure gets mis-aligned, and `">` appears after the content.

Any ideas?

Edit:
I don't know why this was put on hold for not fitting in the Wordpress scope.. the_content() is a Wordpress function, I was clearly having trouble with structuring/SEO for my Wordpress site.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, that is really not how `articleBody` works: http://www.ihid.co.uk/blog/markup-your-blog-using-schema-org

Comment: Thanks, I meant to post back earlier, I did actually fix it by moving the itemprop to the div tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by moving `itemprop="articleBody"` to the `<div>` containing the body.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`esc_attr()`](http://queryposts.com/function/esc_attr/) on data that is displayed in attributes, to prevent broken markup.

However it seems weird overall to use attribute to contain whole post.

Comment: Suggested by schema.org and Google's WMT.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion - does the same as `htmlspecialchars()`, it displays `//` before the content, and `">` after it. And passes script to the meta.

Comment: Is there some way I can auto-add the tag to the posts, rather than the PHP? So like, in the editor, when I publish there's automatically the first part at the beginning, then "> at the end?